# jquery or javascript array appending to div as a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append

my problem is with appending a array into existing div as a text. I cant figure it out why its not working, so i have this code:

```
var raya = ui.item.value + ' ';  
$('#result').append(raya);
var tor = $("#result").text();
```

Above code is working, the value of `raya` (which is string) is appended correctly into `#result`
Problem comes here, the value of `array1` is not appended to `#result2`  and ideas why its not working?

```
var array1 = new Array();
array1 = tor.split( " " );
array1 = $.unique(array1);
$('#result2').append(array1);
return false;
```

(just to mention that everything is holded in 1 function, this cant be the reason, but just to know)

Comment: BTW you don't have to initialize `arra1` with an empty array. You could even write e.g.: `var new_tor = $.unique(tor.split(' ')).join(' ');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this to explicitly convert array to string.

```
$('#result2').append(array1+'');
```

Here's a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/EsnLs/2/

Comment: Just a note : `array1 + ''` works because JS is trying to concatenate `''` with the array thereby calling `.toString()` automatically

Answer (score 6):

That's because `append` expects a string and you're sending it an array.

Two ways to solve it. Use either `.toString()` or `.join()`

```
$('#result2').append(array1.toString()); //inserts a comma separated list
$('#result2').append(array1.join(' '));  //inserts a string separated by what you pass as param
```